# Properties of dry air and gas mixture

Tags: thermodynamics

While studying a heat exchanger, I have encountered a hydrogen rich fluid stream (enters at 90 Celsius and exits at 120 Celsius) which has composition given in the following form:

Air Humidity/Fluid composition: 1% (2.5 bar abs)/Mass fraction of hydrogen=0.02

For the heat exchanger analysis, I need to calculate several properties of this mixture like enthalpy, specific heat.

Property reference softwares like Coolprop and Refprop give data for gas mixtures, but not for air-gas mixtures.

How should I start to calculate the properties of this air-gas mixture?
I guess the humidity can be neglected safely because it is just 1%.

Comment: An air-gas mixture is a gas mixture.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say. so should I just define this as a binary mixture of air and hydrogen. Can you point me to any reference which explains  such mixture property calculations. I guess we need to calculate some equivalent molar mass. I specifically ask for a reference because the refprop and coolprop softwares would not allow me to define a mixture between air and hydrogen.

Comment: Ah I see, the softwares only allow to calculate binary mixtures. Hm, that's a bad limitation. I am afraid I cannot help you with these applications.

Comment: At 2.5 bars, the mixture can be treated as an ideal gas mixture.  The partial molar properties of each species in the gas mixture are the same as those for the pure species at the same temperature and at a pressure equal to the partial pressure in the mixture.

Comment: @ChetMiller Appreciate the comment. I know about the constitutive relationship between partial pressure and mole fraction. Since I aim to analyse a heat exchanger, I am more interested in properties like enthalpy and specific heat. Can you, if possible, elaborate, how should one calculate these properites for the mixture ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "partial molar properties" of the components of a mixture?

Comment: Yes I am. So are you saying the specific heat $c_p$, for this mixture is supposed to be calculated like this ? $c_{p,mixture} = m_{ha}c_{p,ha} + m_{H_2}c_{p,H_2}$, where $ha$ represents humid air while $m_{ha},  m_{H_2}$ imply the respective mass fractions.